# LINQ to SQL for an existing database

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a current project that uses LINQ to SQL to create a database and then to work with the data.

I also have another database which already exists and I do not need to create it. Do you know any tool that can generate the data model for my existing database?

Note: my database is pretty flat so I don't need to be worried about complex relations

Thanks in advance;

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384396.aspx

Answer (score 3):

using visual studio, can't you just create a new .dbml file and point it to your database and then generate all the Object Mappers?

Code Generation in LINQ to SQL:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399400.aspx